# Linux change environmental variables without rebooting for all shells

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, hostname

I am using Fedora 14 and I changed my hostname in `/etc/sysconfig/network` and by using the `hostname` command. The shell prompts correctly display the new hostname. However the terminal titles still display the old hostname. I've tried setting the `$HOSTNAME` variable to the new hostname using `export HOSTNAME=newhostname` but it works only in the current terminal session. When I open a new terminal and type `echo $HOSTNAME` it displays the old one. Is there a way to change `$HOSTNAME` for all shells without rebooting or logging out? I've tried `source /etc/profile` and that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do anything that would push out a environmental variable to already running shells.

So you options are to either start new shells, or do something in each shell that is already running to take the new environmental variable.

The easiest way would be to export the new variable in each shell:

```
export HOSTNAME=mynewhostname
```

Replacing 'mynewhostname' with your new hostname.